# Django-storages force file to upload

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using django-storages to upload my static files to amazon s3. The first upload to s3 worked fine but django-storages doesn't detect that I've changed my static files so it doesn't reupload my changed static files.

How can I force django-storages to upload certain files?

Answer (score 1):

Django storages just changes the backend, to sync up changes within static you still need to run the collectstatic management command of `python manage.py collectstatic`. Please refer to [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)